# Use union/intersection query_posts variables in uri request parameter form?

Tags: query-posts

Usually when I create some form of query, I use an array for my arguments like this:

```
$postslistArgs = array( 
    'child_of' => 320,
    'parent' => 320
);                          
$postslist = get_pages($postslistArgs);
```

There are other times, however, when I need/want to use URI-style query parameters like this:

```
get_pages('child_of=320&parent=320');
```

That's all straightforward, but is there any way possible to use the URI parameter style on more advance union/intersection queries such as `post__not_in` that require an array of IDs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WP_Query uses PHP's native `parse_str` function, which uses the following structure to denote arrays:

```
'post__not_in[]=1&post__not_in[]=2&post__not_in[]=3'
```

is the same as

```
array(
  'post__not_in' => array( 1,2,3 )
)
```

Comment: Wow, never knew this is possible. Thought some stuff is array-only.

Comment: Yeah, it should be noted that this will only work for values for which WordPress' class `WP` will take an array. So, for example, even though you can pass an array of post types to `WP_Query`, you can't send an array of post types through the url; WordPress doesn't understand the request, since `WP` expects a string value only. I think there's a patch that fixes this in 3.1, although I'd have to double check on that.