# Excluding Sticky Posts from The Loop and from WP_Query() in WordPress?

Tags: wp-query, sticky-post

The following snippet is from a sidebar widget that lists "recent posts". Since its on the home page and I feature my lastest sticky post prominently on that page, I want to skip over the sticky in this loop. However, the `post_not_in=sticky_posts` has no effect.

```
<?php
    $the_query = new WP_Query("showposts=$number&offset=1&order=ASC&post_not_in=sticky_posts");

    while ($the_query->have_posts()) : $the_query->the_post();
        $do_not_duplicate = $post->ID; ?>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I took *@tnorthcutt's* answer from [**WordPress' Codex on `query_posts()` about Sticky Parameters**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts#Sticky_Post_Parameters) and created a tandalone example you can drop as `test.php` into your website's root and see it run by navigating to a URL like this, with your domain substituted:

> http://example.com/test.php

Some notes on the code; I had to use **an array equivalent of the query string** you passed to `WP_Query()` because the `post__no_in` argument can't be passed in as a comma delimited string (not sure why, probably an oversight?).

Also I wanted to make sure you know that starting with an `offset=1` (instead of `offset=0`) means you'll be excluding the first post that otherwise would be returned by the query. Of course you'll still get the number of posts specified by `$number` assuming you have that many applicable posts +1.  So here's the code:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type:text/plain');
include "wp-load.php";

$number = 5;

$the_query = new WP_Query(array(
  'showposts' => $number,
  'offset' => 1,  // This will cause the query to skip over first post
  'order' => 'ASC',
  'post__not_in' => get_option("sticky_posts"),
  ));
while ($the_query->have_posts()) : $the_query->the_post();
  the_title(); 
endwhile;
```

Comment: Thanks Mike. Great solution and thoughtful explanation. I really appreciate it. Sorry it took so long to respond :)

Comment: The `post__not_in` question is answered here:
http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/127/use-union-intersection-query-posts-variables-in-uri-request-parameter-form

Comment: *@Dan Gayle*: Good Catch.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to exclude all sticky posts from a query, use

`query_posts(array("post__not_in" =>get_option("sticky_posts")));`

(from [the codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts#Sticky_Post_Parameters))

Looks like that will only work on 3.0 or greater, though: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/excluding-sticky-posts-using-query_posts

Edit: in response to your comment below, try this (I'm not sure this will work, but hopefully it will get you started):

```
<?php 
$args=array(
    'showposts'=>'$number',
    'offset'=>'1',
    'order'=>'ASC',
    'post__not_in'=>get_option("sticky_posts")
    );
$the_query = new WP_Query($args);

    while ($the_query->have_posts()) : $the_query->the_post();

        $do_not_duplicate = $post->ID; ?>
```

Comment: thanks for the response. since I'm not using `query_posts()` in my example, how would I integrate your answer in what I have to work with?

Comment: Scott, see above, I added some more.

Answer (score 1):

[Travis' answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/961/revisions) is fine if you're building your own query, for a secondary loop perhaps, but if you need to modify your main blog query, you can use [pre_get_posts](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/pre_get_posts/) to filter out the sticky posts.

In the example below, I'm only excluding the sticky posts if the query is the blog page, as I still want sticky posts to be returned on taxonomy and search pages etc (I'm displaying sticky posts as featured articles on the main news page).

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'custom_post_archive_changes' );
function custom_post_archive_changes( $query ) {
    if ( is_home() && $query->is_main_query() ) {

        // exclude sticky posts from main news page
        $stickies = get_option("sticky_posts");
        $query->set( 'post__not_in', $stickies );

    }
}
```

Just drop the snippet above in your functions.php file.

Comment: great, work even with ajax later

Answer (score 0):

Just adding a more contemporary answer here, according to the [Wordpress docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/) you can use `ignore_sticky_posts` as an argument to exclude sticky posts from a WP Query object. Here's an example altering the main loop on the posts page:

```
function wpstackexchange_exclude_sticky_posts( $query ) {
    if ( is_home() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $query->set( 'ignore_sticky_posts', true);
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpstackexchange_exclude_sticky_posts' );
```